# Общий box для сгруппированной скрипичной диаграммы

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Как сделать общий box для сгруппированной скрипичной диаграммы?

```
data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hse-ds/iad-intro-ds/master/2022/homeworks/hw03-EDA/german_credit.csv")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (14, 7), dpi = 72)
sns.violinplot(data=data, x="savings", y="age", hue="credit_risk", palette = ['g', 'r'], split=True, density_norm ="area")
plt.show()
```

Получаю вот такое:
[image]

А надо, чтобы обе box частей совпадали:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня ваш код корректно отрабатывает.

Comment: на предыдущей версии эта диаграмма действительно отображается с отцентрированными боксами. на последней - так же, как у вас в примере. что, в общем-то правильно. данные-то разные получаются. Если вы считаете, что это попросту не эстетично, попробуйте заменить бокс на квартили (inner="quart"). вполне годно получается.